# Upload failed on excel document check out and edit

Tags: excel, file-upload

I have an Excel file on Document library. I am working with it daily (Simple edit, update and save). Since yesterday I am getting error message

> "Upload Failed. The server storage quota has been exceeded. Save a copy".

But I have 10GB quota (I have checked in CA).

Other users are fine. I am only the person who get this message. any idea?

[image]

Comment: Are other users fine with the same file or another file? Also, try to clean the deleted objects recycle bin

Comment: Hi Qassas yes only one user is having issue. There are no items in recycle bin.

Comment: on the same file!

Comment: I will check on that, I tried on same file but not on different files.

Comment: It was only that file which is causing the issue. I asked the user to save the file and re-upload it and it is working now.